# Installing x64 gfortran binaries -- issues with libisl.so

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to install gfortran (needed to build Julia) on a fairly locked-down VM.  Following the instructions [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries64Linux) I have extracted everything to gcc-trunk, added gcc-trunk/bin to the path and gfortran --version works.  However, whenever I try to use it I get an error along the lines of

```
bash-3.00$ gfortran hello.f90
/path/to/gcc-trunk/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0/f951: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
bash-3.00$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/path/to/gcc-trunk/lib64
```

where /path/to is the actual (rather long path).  libisl.so.13 was not in that directory, but it was included in the gcc-5-infrastructure file.  I grabbed the libraries from that and added them to the lib64 folder.  Now I get the following error

```
bash-3.00$ gfortran hello.f90
/path/to/gcc-trunk/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0/f951: error while loading shared libraries: /path/to/gcc-trunk/lib64/libisl.so.13: file too short
```

That file contains only the text "libisl.so.13.1.0" which is another file in the same directory that is 1.5 MB in size.  Is there something else I need to make sure gfortran points at the second file?